# Отличие диспетчеризации от подписки на событие

Tags: javascript, jquery, события, javascript-events

Есть код диспетчеризации

```js
    var eventSubscribers = {};

    //Диспетчирезация события
    this.dispatch = function (eventName, payload){
        if(eventSubscribers.hasOwnProperty(eventName)){
            eventSubscribers[eventName].forEach(function (eventHandler){
                eventHandler(payload);
            });
        }

        return true;
    };
```

и подписки на событие

```js
    //Подписка на событие. Возвращает метод отписки handler от события
    this.subscribe = function (eventName, handler){
        if(typeof handler !== 'function'){
            return;
        }

        if(!eventSubscribers.hasOwnProperty(eventName)){
            eventSubscribers[eventName] = [];
        }

        eventSubscribers[eventName].push(handler);

        return function (){
            eventSubscribers[eventName] = eventSubscribers[eventName].filter(function (currentHandler) {
                return currentHandler !== handler;
            });
        }
    }
```

В чем разница по производимому действию диспетчеризации и подписки на событие? Ведь если в коде написано

```js
if(eventSubscribers.hasOwnProperty(eventName)){
            eventSubscribers[eventName].forEach(function (eventHandler){
                eventHandler(payload);
            });
```

то складывается впечатление, что на каждое событие `eventSubscribers[eventName]` подписывается обработчик события `eventHandler`. Такое ощущение, что

```js
eventSubscribers[eventName].forEach(function (eventHandler){
                eventHandler(payload);
            });
```

и

```js
eventSubscribers[eventName].push(handler);
```

делают одно и то же.

Comment: нет, сверху у подписчиков вызывается метод реакции на событие, а снизу просто добавляется ссылка на подписчика.   https://jsmanifest.com/the-publish-subscribe-pattern-in-javascript/ почитайте про паттерн

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов в чем разница выражений `eventSubscribers[eventName].forEach(function (eventHandler){eventHandler(payload); });` и `eventSubscribers[eventName].push(handler);` ?

Comment: у диспетчера есть массив эвентов, в каждом эвенте массив методов от объектов-подписчиков. В первом случае он пробегает по массиву подписчиков и дергает у них callback метод(реакция на событие), а во втором добавляет callback метод себе в массив

Answer (score 0):

Отличие очевидно:

1. добавление функции в массив
2. вызов функции.

Ничего общего.